# Building an Application using MVVM

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I need some help to architect an MVVM application. This time I want to do it in the right way.

My `View` is bound to the `ViewModel` which is bound to the `Model`. No problem there. Displaying data is not the problem, updating it is my problem. 
So when the `View` asks the `ViewModel` to update the `Model` (with a `Command`), which need to handle the logic? 
In my case updating the data is not trivial, there are many calculations with many files.
Also, I really want that the `Model` does not know the business logic. So how to do this? A property in the `Model` which indicates that the he wants to be updated? Or maybe the `ViewModel` have to know the business logic? Is it the Best practice?

Comment: What you aim for (Model having no business logic) is mainly considered a bad practice these days. It's called **Anemic Domain Model** and leads to Service classes which become large very fast or have to many responsibilities, hence it became an anti-pattern. **Rich Domain Model** puts logic that's tied to a certain Domain Entity within the entity itself and only use a thin Service layer for business logic which can't be put into the Model without breaking Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)

Comment: Check out Jimmy Bogards "Crafting Wicked Domain Models" to see why Anemic Domain Model is bad and why Rich Domain Model is much better. https://vimeo.com/43598193

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model is really a snapshot of the state of your business data. Your non-trivial calculations can be encapsulated in services that can be abstracted behind interfaces and injected into your view model. This way your view model knows nothing of these complex processes other than calling them via interface contracts. So your command fires and your view model provides orchestration, your service provides actual business calculations and an updated model would be produced representing the new state of the system.